# IIS URL Rewrite - if query parameter(s) is missing

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

So this is "not your everyday requirement" for today :)

I want to create a rule that will redirect to some other page only if some query parameters are missing.

i found a few examples that will rewrite/redirect if the parameters exists,
but how do i go about if i want to check if they dont exists?

for example, this will test if the parameters exist and redirect based on that:

```
        <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^lon=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;lat=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;zoom=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

how can i change this rule to test if they do NOT exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^((?!regex).)*$ Is the regular expression for does not contain regex. 
read more here http://bloggernitin.blogspot.in/2007/12/regex-for-doesnt-contain.html

If you are looking for something like lon=xyz doesn't exists in params then use this regex
     ^(?!lon=(xyz)) this will check if lon param is not there at the start of string

> ### More examples -
>
> In case you have a case where only zoom param is there is query string and lat/lon are missing
>   e.g. querystring a) "lat=23&zoom=10" b) "zoom=13"
>   regex - ^(?!lon=.*)(?!lat=.*)zoom=([^=&]+)
>   result - a) no match b) match $1= 13
>   now you can give default value to other params.

Comment: i need to check for multiple parameters can you show an example?

Comment: you can use this site to try out your regex patterns
 http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: This will still check for an exact match for the param.
i need to test if the parameter is there and if it has ANY value.

Comment: the example is in the question: `?lon=VALUE_OR_NOVALUE&lat=VALUE_OR_NOVALUE&zoom=VALUE_OR_NOVALUE`