# How to make a rewrite rule in IIS when a querystring parameter is missing?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I want to redirect when a Url is missing a part of the querystring. So, for example

`https://www.example.com?foo=1&bar=2`

is a valid url, don't do anything. But, when the url looks like this:

`https://www.example.com?foo=1` I want to redirect to `https://www.example.com`. 'bar' is missing here, but 'bar' can be any name.

For this I want to use IIS redirects using regex. I've found this question: [IIS URL Rewrite - if query parameter(s) is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116958/iis-url-rewrite-if-query-parameters-is-missing) but I can't get it this to work in my scenario. This is because every other querystring parameter after the `?` can have any name. The first parameter is always `foo`, but the rest of the parameters can have any name.

Can someone help me with the correct regex for this?

Edit:
Real examples of querystrings that must be redirected:

`?crop=0,0,0,0` or
`?crop=2.6111111111111112,0.22222222222222221,0,0`

Both lacks the `&` so they must be redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="query string rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^foo=(\d{0,5})$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Thnx! Can you explain what this regex does?

Comment: @Martijn this will match if query string only contains foo=123 then it will redirect to another site. as you mentioned if another query string parameter is missing it will redirect to another URL.

Comment: Thanks, in this case `foo` can have any value. Does that matter?

Comment: @Martijn could you share some example what URL you want and want you want to redirect?

Comment: @Martijn you could try a regular expression ^crop=[^&\v]*$ or ^[^&\v]*$

Comment: Thnx, will try. Can you explain that a little bit?

Comment: @Martijn this expression  ^[^&\v]*$  will redirect url if query string does not contain &. ^crop=[^&\v]*$ this will redirect if the string does not contain & and corp